# Discord.py "positional argument follows keyword argument" error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This particular line of code is giving me problems

```
message = await message.edit(embed = amountEmbed, components=[Select(placeholder="Select the amount to purchase", options=[SelectOption(label="1 dino toy (50)", value=1)], [SelectOption(label="2 dino toys (100)", value=2)], [SelectOption(label="5 dino toys (250)", value=5)])])
```

And returning this error

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

I can't seem to find it specifically. It indicated the problem is with the 2nd closing parenthesis. I feel like this is a simple error but I can't seem to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one reason why breaking long lines into multiple lines can be helpful. Let's look at what your line actually says:

```
message.edit(
    embed = amountEmbed, 
    components=[
        Select(
            placeholder="Select the amount to purchase", 
            options=[
                SelectOption(label="1 dino toy (50)", value=1)
            ], 
            [SelectOption(label="2 dino toys (100)", value=2)],
            [SelectOption(label="5 dino toys (250)", value=5)]
        )
    ]
)
```

You can see that the `Select` is called with arguments `placeholder=...`, `options=[...]`, and then two unnamed (positional) arguments.

Unfamiliar with discord.py but my guess is you wanted your `SelectOption`s to all be in one list, like

```
options=[
    SelectOption(label="1 dino toy (50)", value=1), 
    SelectOption(label="2 dino toys (100)", value=2),
    SelectOption(label="5 dino toys (250)", value=5)
]
```